# Did Amazon give permission to be included in the movie Nomadland?

Tags: nomadland

In this movie, *[Nomadland](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9770150/)*, Amazon is seen on several occasions, both from outside and from inside of Amazon warehouse.

[image]

[image]

I am wondering if Amazon had given their permission to be included in this movie?
As Amazon is portrayed as the representative of American Capitalism and the vibe of this movie is more sympathetic towards nomad Americans and against the tyranny of the dollar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to ***The Hollywood Reporter***](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/features/director-chloe-zhao-arrives-with-hot-oscar-contender-nomadland-and-next-years-eternals):

> In order to gain Zhao’s crew access to shoot the actress working in an Amazon fulfillment center, **McDormand wrote a letter to Jeff Blackburn, Amazon’s senior vp business and corporate development**. "I explained that we were telling the story about a woman who did migrant work and one of the jobs that she did was CamperForce with Amazon," says McDormand, referring to a kind of traveling retiree army that takes seasonal work for the online retailer during the holidays. "It was right before they started giving people $15 an hour. This was a really smart move for them because ... we are telling a story about a person who is benefiting from hard work, and working at the Amazon fulfillment center is hard work, but it pays a wage." One downside for the retailer, notes McDormand, is that "some people got some packages that I packaged that were pretty bad."

Comment: The other thing to note, of course, is that it's illegal in most jurisdictions to film or photograph from inside the boundary of any private property without express permission. That's definitely one of those occasions where it is not easier to apologise afterwards than ask permission first ;) It's also got to be tough to sneak 50 people in through security if they don't know you're coming.